# How to access constructor argument that's not member variable in init function?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a custom layout as below

```
class CustomComponent : FrameLayout {

    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {
        initAttrs(attrs)
    }

    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
        initAttrs(attrs)
    }

    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int, defStyleRes: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes) {
        initAttrs(attrs)
    }

    init {
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_custom_component, this, true)
    }

    fun initAttrs(attrs: AttributeSet?) {
        val typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.custom_component_attributes, 0, 0)
        my_title.text = resources.getText(typedArray
                .getResourceId(R.styleable.custom_component_attributes_custom_component_title, R.string.component_one))
        typedArray.recycle()
    }
}
```

Now for each constructor, I have to explicitly call `initAttrs(attrs)` as I can't find  way to access `attrs` in my `init` function.

Is there a way I could access `attrs` in `init` function, so I could call `initAttrs(attrs)` from `init` instead of having to explicitly call it in each of the constructor?

Comment: How do you expect this could work if not all of the constructors have the `attrs` parameter?

Comment: When it is not provided, ideally then we should skip calling `initAttr`. You ask a good question, as I think it is not possible when `attrs` is not available in all constructor. But I thought of asking to confirm with the Kotlin expert out there, given reading `attrs` is quite common in building custom layout, and in java, there's some nice way of handling it without need to replicate the call of `initAttr` all over the places.

Comment: you can use `lateinit var attrs : AttributeSet?` and set the value in each constructor and then use it in initAttrs()

Comment: Thanks Debu. That would defeat the purpose, as I still have to set the variable in each constructor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a constructor with default arguments:

```
class CustomComponent @JvmOverloads constructor(
  context: Context, 
  attrs: AttributeSet? = null, 
  defStyle: Int = 0
) : FrameLayout(context, attrs, defStyle) {

    fun init {
      // Initialize your view
    }
}
```

The `@JvmOverloads` annotation tells Kotlin to generate three overloaded constructors so they can be called in Java as well.

In your `init` function, `attrs` becomes available as a nullable type:

```
fun init {
  LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_custom_component, this, true)

  attrs?.let {
        val typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(it, R.styleable.custom_component_attributes, 0, 0)
        my_title.text = resources.getText(typedArray
                .getResourceId(R.styleable.custom_component_attributes_custom_component_title, R.string.component_one))
        typedArray.recycle()
  }
}
```

Note the usage of `it` in the `let` block.

Comment: Excellent answer!!

Comment: This can cause unpredictable behavior with switches and certain design support library components because of assumed `defStyle = 0`.